# Can the bounty rules be changed so that users can offer bounties lower than fifty points?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Can the bounty rules be changed so that users can offer bounties lower than fifty points? I think that Ask Ubuntu would benefit from allowing users to offer five-point, ten-point, and fifteen-point bounties. Some users may want to offer bounties, but they do not want to give up so many reputation points (like me for this question [What are the steps to modify a filesystem (say XFS)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307279/steps-to-modify-a-filesystem-say-xfs-in-ubunut-linux?rq=1)). If users could offer smaller amounts, perhaps more bounties will be made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make that amount in upvotes easily. If bounties are so low, they diminish in value, when you give a bounty you're effectively saying "I really want eyes on this question, so much so I've given X of my hard earned reputation". If you're uncomfortable giving the minimum 50 rep, especially if a question is difficult, a 5 or 10 rep incentive is tantamount to just one or two upvotes. You have to just weigh the cost vs desire.

That being said, there are a lot of things you can do *other* than giving a bounty to bring attention to your question. Editing it to provide steps you've done (not in this case, since it's not your question), etc can help bring attention to a question.